# Prevent long x-axis ticklabels from being cut off in bar charts with plotly in R

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I am trying to use `plotly` to plot a bar chart with long strings as x-axis labels. However, these strings are cut off by `plotly` like this shown here:

[image: Plotly chart axis]

Going through the list of attributes of `plotly` axis, I've tried setting such as `tickangle` (which doesn't make sense, I realize now) and several others, but all are of no use.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can adjust the margins in a plotly layout in the `layout` function.

Reproducible example since one was not provided:

```
d <- data.frame(traitMean = apply(iris[-5], 2, mean))
# long labels
labs <- c("Long name for this", "Long name for that",
          "Long names everywhere", "Petal Width")
```

If you plot this with the default margins, the labels will be cutoff:

```
# example where ticklabels are cutoff
plot_ly(y = d[["traitMean"]], x = labs, type = "bar") %>% 
    layout(xaxis = list(tickangle = 45))
```

You can adjust the bottom margin from the default in the `margin` argument of `layout`.  `margin` takes a named list where `b` is the name for the "bottom" margin.  160 px works in this example, but you may need to find a value that works for your labels.

```
plot_ly(y = d[["traitMean"]], x = labs, type = "bar") %>% 
    layout(margin = list(b = 160), xaxis = list(tickangle = 45))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think this works well for my purpose, to fully display the label names.

Comment: I have the same problem with javascript what should I do

Comment: Me too, in Javascript.

Comment: Do the.... same? Find where is your layout's margin hiding.
Here's what you can do with it: [link](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-margin)

Comment: I have found using the margin argument useful.
https://plotly.com/r/reference/#layout-margin

So for example

m <- list(
    l = 50,
    r = 100,
    b = 100,
    t = 50,
    pad = 40
  )
  
  plot = plot %>% layout(margin = m)

where l, r, t, b are the left, right, top and bottom margins added in pixels.

Answer (score 5):

Text can get cut off on bars when the `textposition="outside"`. To avoid this, along with setting the margins to fix y-axis label truncation, set the `cliponaxis = FALSE`  to fix the value label truncation.

Here is an example of the value label truncation in spite of adding top and bottom margins to remove y-axis label truncation:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(
x = c("1. Group 1", "2. Txn","3. AOV","4. Account/Recv CV","5. Cost %","6. Lost %","7. Take Rate","8. Group 2"),
  y = c(3.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.8),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "waterfall",
  measure = c("relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative","total"),
  text = c(3.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.8), textposition = 'outside'
) %>% 
layout(margin = list(b = 20,t=20))
```

Resulting Graph has the value 3.8 cut off. 
[image: Value Labels Truncated]

When you add `cliponaxis = FALSE` the cut off is removed

```
plot_ly(
  x = c("1. Group 1", 
        "2. Txn",
        "3. AOV",
        "4. Account/Recv CV",
        "5. Cost %",
        "6. Lost %", 
        "7. Take Rate",
        "8. Group 2"),
  y = c(3.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.8),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "waterfall",
  measure = c("relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative","total"),
  text = c(3.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.8), textposition = 'outside', cliponaxis = FALSE
) %>% 
layout(margin = list(b = 20,t=20))
```

[image: Truncation removed after adding cliponaxis = FALSE]

Hope this helps