# How to make plotly parallel_categories plot narrower so labels would fit

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I have an object of association rules which I would like to create a parralel categories plot out of. However the attributes in my dataframe are quite long sometimes for example "pm1-dobro,pm25-slabo,o3-dobro". They have to be like this since they represent association rules which go together.

```py
    import plotly.express as px

    fig = px.parallel_categories(
            arules, 
            dimensions=['antecedents', 'consequents'],
            color="support", 
            color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Inferno,
            labels={'antecedents':'Antecedents', 'consequents':'Consequents'},
        )
    fig.show()
```

[Plot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkdHy.jpg)

The problem is that the labels on the right and also on the left are going out of frame. Even if I zoom out of the browser window the labels are still cut/missing.

How can I make the plot with the lines in the middle more narrow so I can display all my labels?

And how could I move the "support" label on the right so it would not overlap with the labels?

I have tried to reduce the font size like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253481/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-labels-or-otherwise-make-them-more-readabl) but I still could not fit all the labels in so the plot would look okay.

Answer (score 0):

If you have long labels and are not fully shown in the window you just have to set left and right margin values.

For modifying the colorbar position you define a positive value if you want it more to the right or a negative value to set it more to the left.

```
fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(l=500, r=500, t=5, b=5),
    coloraxis_colorbar_x=1.33
)
```

[This question for plotly in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105723/prevent-long-x-axis-ticklabels-from-being-cut-off-in-bar-charts-with-plotly-in-r) helped me out for the hidden labels and also this [GeeksForGeeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-plotly-how-to-set-colorbar-position-for-a-choropleth-map/) helped for the colorbar fix.